# How do I shift the values of every column in a data frame to the left or right?

Tags: r

So I have a dataset where all values are 1 column to the left of where they should be and the rownames have become the values from the 1st column. I assume this is an issue with the excel file I am reading in. Unfortunately I don't have access to this excel file so I can't quickly fix it. I am looking for a way to shift the values of each column over to the right by one column.

For example this is what I have now:

```
   A  B  C
1  6 11 16
2  7 12 17
3  8 13 18
4  9 14 19
5 10 15 20
```

And this is what I want it to be with each value being shifted to the right and the rownames just being the rownumbers:

```
  A  B  C
1 1  6 11
2 2  7 12
3 3  8 13
4 4  9 14
5 5 10 15
```

I have searched around but haven't found much except for how to shift rows up/down or how to shift column names left/right. I want the column names to stay the same and the rows to stay the same just each value to be moved over 1 column

Comment: `df[,2:3] = df[,1:2] ; df[,1] = rownames(df)`

Comment: Thanks. I was making that way harder than it actually was in my head. Turns out this was super simple

Comment: @d.b It’s almost certainly more efficient to change the `colnames` rather than copying columns to and fro.

Comment: For this example, just do `df - nrow(df)`

Comment: Also `df[] <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df[head(seq_along(df), -1)])` if you have more columns.

Comment: @imo That's one elegant piece of code.